# conflict between use IO::Tee & an END block

Tags: perl, archlinux

This script, `IOTee.pl`, reports it took 0 seconds to run:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use IO::Tee

# create a time check:
END { print "This Perl program ran for ", time() - $^T, " seconds.\n"}
```

but it also reports:

> Can't locate object method "END" via package "1" (perhaps you forgot to load "1"?) at IOTee.pl line 6.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at IOTee.pl line 6.

- why?

Comment: Show the full code that gets the error

Comment: @ysth, I've changed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the semicolon after "use IO::Tee".

So the `END { print ... }` is being used as the import list to pass to IO::Tee::import.  And that syntax is like `print { expression-giving-a-filehandle } output-stuff`; what's in the `{}` (which is `1`, because that's what a successful print returns) is an object to call the END method on.

Comment: Yes, and that very basic mistake of mine makes this into a misleading question...